# How can I call render_option() of forms.Select in Django?

Tags: django, django-forms

```
class MySelect(forms.Select):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.variations = kwargs.pop('variations')
        super(MySelect, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def render_option(self, selected_choices, option_value, option_label):
        return '<option whatever> {} </option>'.format(self.variations[0])

class CartItemForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = CartItem
        fields = (
            'variation',
            'width',
            'height',
            'quantity',
        )


    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        product = kwargs.pop('product')
        try:
            cart = kwargs.pop('cart')
            self.cart = cart
        except:
            pass

        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)    

        variation_field = self.fields['variation']
        variation_field.queryset = Variation.objects.filter(
            product=product
        )
        variation_field.widget = MySelect(variations=variation_field.queryset)

    def save(self):
        cart_item = super().save(commit=False)
        cart_item.cart = self.cart
        cart_item.save()

        return cart_item
```

But it doesn't call `render_option()` so it doesn't show anything in `template`...

What's wrong with that?

Comment: I comment that out  cuz I cannot access `self.xxx` in the `Meta` class. It occurs error

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass variable as argument in Meta class in Django Form?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39785703/how-to-pass-variable-as-argument-in-meta-class-in-django-form)

Comment: What's the `Django` version you were using?

Answer (score 2):

The question is faulty. When you customize a Widget then you need to override the proper functions. Then the framework will call it for you at the right moment, but you never have to call them explicitly.

What happened is that you encountered (maybe inherited, as in my case) a code sample which meant to work with earlier versions of `Django`. In those earlier versions the `render_option` was the right function, but in my case I don't see it any more in Django 1.11 (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/releases/1.11/#changes-due-to-the-introduction-of-template-based-widget-rendering). The only proper thing is to convert the sample, find the existing function(s) we can override to achieve the desired results.